# How can i redirect a register user to pay a specific amount before he or she have access to loggin to the dashboard?

Tags: plugins

I'm building an investment website and I want all user to register with a specific fee before seeing his/dashboard, please how can I achieve this

Comment: What are you using as a payment gateway? You can manage the access to the dashboard with user roles, so you give newly registered users one role and then when their payment completes switch that to another role with has access to the dashboard.

Comment: However what you're asking for is fairly complex, so I'd look an existing subscription or membership plugin as a starting point at least.

Comment: I'm using pay stack payment gateway